# Ruby add initialized object to class array

Tags: ruby

I am unable to figure out or find any information on how to push the initialized object pointer to an array accessed from a class level variable. Here is an example.

```
Class Color
  @@colors = Array.new

  def initialize
   @@colors << red
  end

  def self.list
    @@colors.each do |color|
      puts color.to_hex
    end
  end
end

red = Color.new
```

Thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `self` to reference the current instance of the class:

```
class Color
  @@colors = Array.new

  def initialize
   @@colors << self
  end

  def self.list
    @@colors.each do |color|
      puts color.to_hex
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way:

```
class Color
  @colors = []

  def self.new(*args, &blk)
    @colors << super
  end
  def self.list
    puts @colors.map(&:to_hex)
  end
end

red = Color.new

Color.list
```

Personally, I feel uncomfortable doing class-level stuff in the instance initializer, it just doesn't feel right. The class is a completely independent object, having the instance know too much about the class smells of bad OO.

Comment: I like the idea of separating class and instance level more clearly. Never thought of it that way but it just makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer class instance variables over class variables. Class variables are like globals - if you change it in a subclass it will also change the variable in the superclass. This is rarely the wanted effect. Here's @JKillian's code rewritten with class instance variables:

```
class Color
  class << self
    attr_accessor :colors
  end
  @colors = Array.new

  def initialize
   Color.colors << self
  end

  def self.list
    @colors.each do |color|
      puts color.to_hex
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate approach and the apt description of why!